# Bull js blocks express api requests until jobs finish

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, bull

I have a job server running [Bull](https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull) and express.

**Server requirements**

Receive a request containing an object and use that object as an input to a local programme (no other choice) which takes several minutes to a couple hours to run. The jobs **MUST** be run one after the other in the order they are received (no way round this).

**TL;DR Server:**

```js
// Set up Bull queue and process
const osmQueue = new Bull("osm", {
    redis: {
        port: "6969",
    },
});
osmQueue.process((job) => {
    extractOms(job);
});

// Process function
const extractOms = (job) => {
    // I have tried execSync also
    spawnSync("programme", [
        "this",
        "programme",
        "takes",
        "~30",
        "minutes",
        "to",
        "run",
        "and",
        "requires",
        "full",
        "system",
        "resources (cannot share system resources with another job)",
    ]);

return
};

// Express server with single route
const app = express();
app.post("/create-map-job", (req, res) => {
    console.log("fired"); // Fires on first request. Blocked on second until job done
    osmQueue.add(req.body);
    res.send("job successfully queued"); // Returns on first request. Blocked on second until job done
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`);
});
```

**The problem:**

1. When I send data to this route everything works exactly as expected. The job begins, and I receive the 'job successfully queued' back from the server.
2. When I send data to the server a second time (*while the previous job is still running*) the console.log in the route does not fire and the request hangs until the existing job is finished. Once the existing job finishes the request is acknowledged and the next job is queued up.

**Things I've tried:**

1. Using spawn() instead of spawnSync(). While this means the requests are no longer blocked, it means that all jobs are executed at the same time. I have looked into Bull's concurrency however when the child_process is asynchronus like spawn() or exec() the job is marked as complete as soon as the programme is successfully begun - it does not wait for the spawn() to complete. This means that the server THINKS that the job is complete and happilly loads in another job and I run out of memory very quickly and the system crashes. **I cannot limit or control memory usage at all.. if anything I need more memory for each process, so I have to have only 1 running at a time**
2. Simple calling res.send() BEFORE osmQueue.add(). This has no change on the behaviour.
3. Using the limiter: {max, duration} option on the queue. This works if I set to limiter duration to say 5 hours, but that massively reduces the amount of work I can do at once to an unacceptably low level.
4. I have been reading on this and searching for quite some time, but I cannot find a similar question to mine.

**Questions:**

1. Why does the execution of a system process block node/express after it already executed res.send()?
2. Is there another library I should be using?
3. Any insight from someone in the know is hugely appreciated.

Let me know if there is anything else I can add to this and I will do so quickly.

**TL;DR REQUIREMENT:**

*Execute a system process as part of a job, in order, one after the other without blocking the server from queuing more jobs or responding to requests while the existing job is running.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved; it is amazing how writing out a question in full can inspire the brain and make you look at things again. Leaving this here for future Googlers.

See this from the Bull docs > https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull#separate-processes

I needed to invoke Bull's separate-processes. This allows me to run blocking code in a process separate from the node/express process which means future requests are not blocked, even though synchronous code is running.

```js
// osm.processor.js
module.exports = extractOms (job) {
    spawnSync("programme", [
        "this",
        "programme",
        "takes",
        "~30",
        "minutes",
        "to",
        "run",
        "and",
        "requires",
        "full",
        "system",
        "resources (cannot share system resources with another job)",
    ]);
    return;
}
```

```js
// queue.js
osmQueue.process(
    "/path/to/file/above/job-server/processors/osm.processor.js"
);
```

This spawns the blocking work in a separate process. Thanks Bull!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying and documenting it.